# Errors in measuring devices

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

I have a question regarding what we mean when we report the error in any measurement.

Let's say I have a measuring scale which has markings in mm. Therefore any measurement I make has a limit on the precision.

We might want to report the length of the thing we are measuring as x mm +- 0.5 mm. Here we say 0.5 mm because of the discretized nature of the scale. Any value in [x-0.5,x+0.5] is reported as x mm. So in this approach, we might say that the error is 0.5 mm.

Instead, if I assume that I have a uniform distribution in [x-0.5,x+0.5] then when I calculate the standard deviation using the usual methods of probability, I get standard deviation = 1mm/sqrt(12).

The second method is telling me that my device has a smaller error than the first.

Any ideas/suggestions how to think about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the assumption of uniform distribution might be the problem. You can't be sure you are ever precisely at x-0.5+0.0000000000000001. You effectively have a 0% chance of getting this result. Weight measurements according to the actual associated readouts of the device.

Suppose you know your length is between $\in [x,x+1]$. If you only report measurements in terms of integers, then you'll only ever note the length as x or x+1. If you always report the length as x since its the greatest integer number of millimeters less than your length, then you'll have zero standard deviation. Your weights are 100% for x and 0% for anything greater. If your length is as likely to be measured as x as (x+1), then your weights are 50% for x, 50% for (x+1) and 0 for anything in between. The associated standard deviation is 0.5.

The error is always going to be smaller than 1mm but you don't know how much smaller with  much accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I would typically estimate the "overage" as my best tenth-of-a-millimeter guess. Also, statistics normally applies to a population size that is large enough (e.g., 30 measurements). If you take just one measurement, a standard deviation calculation probably doesn't apply.